# React Native Select Dropdown in React Hook Forms

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I have a select that I want to implement with react hook form in React Native, everything is ok but I can't get the value form the select, because value is not a prop of the select.

How can I get the value of the selected option?

```js
import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown'
import { Control, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
```

It's the select

```js
<Controller
  name={name}
  control={control}
  rules={{
    required:required,
  }}
  render={({field:{value,onChange}})=> {
     return(
        <>
          {label &&
             <Text className="text-black text-sm mb-1">
                {label}
              </Text>
            }
            <SelectDropdown
              data={data}
              onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
                console.log(selectedItem.id)
              }}
              renderDropdownIcon={isOpened => {
                return <FontAwesome
                  name={isOpened ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'}
                  color={theme.colors.azul}
                  size={12}
                />;
              }}
              renderCustomizedRowChild={(item, index) => {
                return (
                  <View className="ml-5">
                    <Text>{item?.quantidade}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              }}
              buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
                return selectedItem.quantidade;
              }}
              defaultButtonText={'Seleçõe uma opção'}
              buttonStyle={{
                width: '100%',
                height: 30,
                backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                borderRadius: 8,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: theme.colors.azul
              }}
              buttonTextStyle={{
                color: '#444',
                textAlign: 'left',
                fontSize:14,
                fontFamily:theme.fonts.MontserratMedium
              }}
          />
      </>
  )}}
/>
```

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manage the `value` and `onChange` in the `render` function of Controller. 
`onChange` provided by `Controller` is used to update the value in the react-hook-form form state, when an option is selected in the `SelectDropdown`, you have to call `onChange(selectedItem.id)` to update the form value with the selected option's id (or any other value you want to store)

```js
<View>
 {label && <Text>{label}</Text>}
 <SelectDropdown
    data={data}
    onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
    onChange(selectedItem.id); // update the form value here
    }}
    // ... other props for SelectDropdown
 />
</View>
```

see [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller/controller)

> `onChange`: A function which sends the input's value to the library. 
> It should be assigned to the `onChange` prop of the input and value should not be undefined.
> This prop update [formState](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/formstate) and you should avoid manually invoke [setValue](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/setvalue) or other API related to field update